# [PhoneGap][Android] How to detect enter key

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have issue with phonegap on android, i have a simple html

```
 <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
    <input id="target" type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and a simple javascript

```
$("#target").on("keypress", function(event){               
    alert(event.which);
 });
```

When i press enter key, nothing happen, other keys work. I use phonegap 2.9.0 and android 2.3.5

Please help me

Answer (score 5):

You can use the keycodes to detect which key was pressed. I have an example here:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4bcWn/)

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="target">Type Something:</label>
        <input id="target" type="text" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#target").on("keypress", function(event){               
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("The enter key was pressed");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it in my mobile app but was not with phonegap so not positive it will work, But worth a try.

```
   $('#target').submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
 alert(event.which);
}
```